# Prove that x is a boundary point of S

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Given a set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a point $x$ with the property that every ball $B(x;r)$ contains both interior and exterior points of $S$. Prove that $x$ is a boundary point of S.

My attempt
Proof. Suppose $x$ is not a boundary point, then $x$ is either an interior point or an exterior point. Assume $x$ is an interior point for this case, the case where $x$ is an exterior point follows the same argument. Since $x$ is an interior point, there is an open ball $B(x;a)$ that is a subset of $B(x;r)$. But this implies that $x$ is also an exterior point, which is a contradiction. Hence $x$ cannot be an interior point, by the same argument $x$ cannot be an exterior point. Thus x is a boundary point. QED

Any suggestions or comments?

Comment: What is your definition of a boundary point? Because what you're trying to prove is what many people consider the definition.

Comment: What do you mean by what is my definition of a point?

Comment: Oops omitted a word. My bad.

Comment: A boundary point is a point which is neither exterior to S nor an interior point of S.

Comment: I don't understand this line of your proof: "Since x is an interior point, there is an open ball B(x;a) that is a subset of B(x;r)"

Comment: Since x is an interior point there exist a neighborhood B(x;a) whose center is x with radius a such that B(x;a) is a subset of S. From the question, all x has the property of B(x;r), so B(x;a) is a subset of B(x;r).

Comment: Yes that's what I though you meant. Well then I don't think you need the extra variable $r$. The question quantifies over all $r$. So just set $r = a$ and you have your contradiction immediately.

Comment: So is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes. As @Ali's answer suggests, there's not much to prove. An interior point is defined as having some ball around it containing all points in $S$. Same for exterior, except all points are outside of $S$. But the definition of $x$ in the question violates both of these. So the only remaining option is that $x$ is a boundary point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your proof certainly is correct. But that is the definition of boundary point, proof wasn't needed.